# Unity web player on windows 7

Tags: unity-game-engine, windows-7-x64, unity-web-player

My machine is Windows 7. I build my unity scene for the web platform. I click .html file; it says that download unity player. I click on image to download the unity player.

[image]

I install unityplayer.exe and run it. I reopen the HTML file; it says that download unity player again.

I don't understand why it doesn't work. How can I install unity player properly?

Comment: Unity Webplayer is no longer actively supported by Unity and is DEPRECATED, which means things like this will occur from time to time and there's no intention of fixing them. Consider using another platform or not using the Webplayer aspect of Unity3D

Answer (score 0):

As Martin mentioned in the comments, Unity Web Player is no longer supported by Unity.

This is because Google announced a plan to deprecate support for NPAPI plugins, such as the Unity Web Player. See the full article [here](http://blogs.unity3d.com/2015/10/08/unity-web-player-roadmap/).

I'd suggest switching platforms for your game :-)